# React App scaling differently for mobile on localhost vs on aws

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I've recently built a react app which looked great on both mobile and desktop. I was really excited to deploy but then noticed it looked entirely different on aws vs running locally on my machine. My machine is running macos and the server is running linux however I couldn't find a real reason for that to make a difference. The first screenshot is running on localhost on and does scale the page properly, whereas the second screenshot is the exact same code on aws ec2 which just looks like it doesn't even realize it's mobile. I thought it may be related to the

```
<meta
  name="viewport"
  content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes"
/>
```

in the index.html however no matter what I did I seemed to end up with the same result.

[Screenshot showing proper scaling (localhost)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSNAf.jpg)

[Screenshot showing improper scaling (aws ec2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWwuQ.jpg)

Comment: there is a high chance that this is related to some assets that you have on your local. Here is what you can try. If this is a git repo, clone (do not copy the existing folder) the repo into a separate directory on you local machine and try running.

Comment: Try removing the `user-scalable=yes` part, and check again. Making a long shot here